# pandas str contains with maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data-frames, one of them contains strings and the other contains a timestamp and a string.

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tim', 'Timothy', 'Kistian', 'Kris cole','Ian'], 
        'Age':['1-2-1997', '21-3-1998', '19-6-2000', '18-4-1996','12-12-2001']})

df1= pd.DataFrame({'string':['Ti', 'Kri' ,'ian' ], 
            'MaxDate':[None, None, None]})
```

I want to assign to `MaxDate` column the maximum date of a `str.contains(df1['string'][0]` operation on df2:

for example: `df2[df2.Name.str.contains(df1['string'][0])]` gives me 2 records
[image: example]

I want to assign the maximum of these values to `MaxDate` corresponding to 'ti':

ie o/p for the first iteration will be:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'string':['Ti', 'Kri' ,'ian' ], 
                'MaxDate':['1-2-1997', None, None]})
```

How can I do this for all entries of df1 using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need loop solution create list of dictionaries with `max` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df2['Age'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Age'], dayfirst=True)

out = []
for x in df1['string']:
    m = df2.loc[df2.Name.str.contains(x), 'Age'].max()
    out.append({'string': x, 'MaxDate': m})
    
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df)
  string    MaxDate
0     Ti 1998-03-21
1    Kri 1996-04-18
2    ian 2000-06-19
```